# TypeScript ругается на 'initialValue' в методах массивов

Tags: javascript, typescript

Ругается на index, пишет:

> [ts] Cannot find name 'index'. [2304]

```
  const result: any = sort.map((val, i) => ({ ...val, value: index++ }), index = 1)
```

Пример тестовый, мне нужно работать именно со значением index

Comment: в спеке указано что второй параметр в `Array.prototype.map` это `this`, что там делает `index = 1`?

Comment: Хочу хранить переменную index как this и использовать её

Comment: @АлександрСинников, вот кстати в этой формулировке намного понятнее, чем в вопросе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`initialValue` - есть только у [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). У остальных методов, вторым аргументом передается `this`, который будет использован в callback, переданном в первом аргументе.

Но даже не смотря на это, ошибка просто в том, что нигде не объявлена переменная `index`.

Для решения достаточно объявить ее:

```
var index = 1;
const result: any = sort.map((val, i) => ({ ...val, value: index++ }))
```

<sub>Хотя странно, почему тут не использовать параметр `i`, в котором и передается индекс текущего элемента.</sub>

---

> именно в thisArg я хочу объявлять свою переменную index

**Объявлять** внутри выражения нельзя. Однако можно передать туда объект с полем `index`, заменив при этом стрелочную функцию на обычную

```
const result: any = sort.map(function(val, i) { return { ...val, value: this.index++ };}, {index: 1});
```

Однако в этом случае доступа извне к нему тоже не будет, поэтому в любом случае если `index` понадобится снаружи, придется объявлять переменную отдельно.

---

> Хочу хранить переменную index как this и использовать её

Для этого эта переменная в любом случае должна быть объявлена и передана вторым параметром. Однако с просто числом данный вариант невозможен, так как его невозможно будет изменить между вызовами.

То есть, сделав `this++` внутри callback будет ошибка *Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix operation*

Comment: Я специально написал что пример тестовый чтобы не предлагали использовать индекс. 
initialValue есть во всех методах массивов

Comment: @АлександрСинников, в любом случае - в ответе есть решение проблемы.

Comment: ответ не получен, мне нужно работать именно с index переданным в том виде как я написал в примере

Comment: @АлександрСинников, перечитай ответ еще раз. Конкретно начиная со второго абзаца. Плюс определись - это тестовый пример, или ты именно так и хочешь чтобы было.

Comment: Повторю в очередной раз, возможно с этого раза будет понятно. Пример тестовый, не надо мне предлагать использовать i вместо index который я явно указал в конце функции map. Пример тестовый но он должен работать. 
Вот вырезка из документации:

var new_array = arr.map(function callback(currentValue, index, array) { 
    // Возвращает элемент для new_array 
}[, thisArg])

и именно в thisArg я хочу объявлять свою переменную index и только тут

Comment: @АлександрСинников, обновил ответ.

Comment: Вы правы, передавать this как объект корректней однако value: this.index++ не будет правильно отрабатывать в стрелочных функциях

Comment: @АлександрСинников, именно поэтому `thisArgs` для стрелочных функций вообще можно не использовать, так как у них нельзя установить `this`.

Comment: @АлександрСинников, и все возвращается к самому первому варианту: просто объявить переменную извне, если так нужна стрелочная функция.

Comment: введите в консоль:
`var result = [1,2,3].map(_ => ({ value: index++ }), index = 1)`
result заполнится правильно, однако такое объявление index для ts ошибочно, и мне хотелось бы решить её оставив index внутри this. Неужели нету решений без выноса этой переменной за пределы map?

Comment: @АлександрСинников, ты путаешь теплое с мягким :-) в яваскрипте в нестрогом режиме, данный код действительно будет работать, но только в нестрогом, в котором присваивание значения создает переменную в глобальной области видимости. То есть, это тот же самый вынос переменной за пределы `map`, просто ты руками не пишешь `var index`

Comment: Вот теперь всё стало понятно, благодарю